# $("#submit").click not working :/

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried everything I can think of to get this "send" button to work, but I'm not very good at javascript :(

http://www.kimscakes.biz/contactme.php

Prehaps someone here can tell me where i'm going wrong?

Many thanks

Gem

Comment: You should post the relevant code instead of expecting others to chase after it in your link.

Comment: /\ this - we need the JavaScript and possibly the form, or at least the submit button.

Comment: Apologies, will edit the question

Comment: You are binding the submit before the element exists, move the code after the form or put it inside `$(document).ready`

Comment: Additional to Esailija's comment, your HTML is a complete mess... you've got elements after the `</body>`, and no closing `</html`>; http://validator.w3.org.

Comment: In future please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to your website. Your post should standalone from any other resource. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it for more info

Comment: Sorry Matt - first question, lesson learned :) Thanks for you help though guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding the submit before the element exists, move the code after the form or put it inside `$(document).ready`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#submit").click(function () {
        console.log("button clicked");
        // declare these vars
        var name = jQuery("#name");
        var email = jQuery("#email");
        var message = jQuery("#message");
        var human = jQuery("#human");
        var success = jQuery("#success");
        var error = jQuery("#error");
        // reset these vars
        success.html("");
        error.html("");
        // ajax call to script.php
        jQuery.getJSON("mailer.php", {
            name: name.val(),
            email: email.val(),
            message: message.val(),
            human: human.val()
        }, function (html) {
            // if html from script.php == 1, happy days
            if (html == '1') {
                jQuery("#contact").hide()
                success.html("Thank You, your message has been sent.")
                error.show()
            }
            else {
                error.html(html)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you! I will fix the html in a sec, but at least the form now works :D